# Selecting multiple rows of hierarchical DataFrame with Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex with 3 levels. Suppose I have the following data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColB': {('A1', 'B1', 1): 'cb1',
  ('A1', 'B1', 2): 'cb2',
  ('A1', 'B2', 1): 'cb3',
  ('A1', 'B2', 2): 'cb4',
  ('A2', 'B1', 1): 'cb5',
  ('A2', 'B1', 2): 'cb6',
  ('A2', 'B2', 1): 'cb7',
  ('A2', 'B2', 2): 'cb8'},
 'colA': {('A1', 'B1', 1): 'ca1',
  ('A1', 'B1', 2): 'ca2',
  ('A1', 'B2', 1): 'ca3',
  ('A1', 'B2', 2): 'ca4',
  ('A2', 'B1', 1): 'ca5',
  ('A2', 'B1', 2): 'ca6',
  ('A2', 'B2', 1): 'ca7',
  ('A2', 'B2', 2): 'ca8'}})

        ColB colA
A1 B1 1  cb1  ca1
      2  cb2  ca2
   B2 1  cb3  ca3
      2  cb4  ca4
A2 B1 1  cb5  ca5
      2  cb6  ca6
   B2 1  cb7  ca7
      2  cb8  ca8
```

Now, I have a MultiIndex object that contains the index of the first two levels, like

```
MultiIndex([('A1', 'B2'),
            ('A2', 'B1')],
           )
```

I want to use that MultiIndex to select all the rows corresponding to that MultiIndex including all the index from level 3, such as,

```
        ColB colA
A1 B2 1  cb3  ca3
      2  cb4  ca4
A2 B1 1  cb5  ca5
      2  cb6  ca6
```

How can I do this? I've been searching for answer for hours but I still have no clue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with remove 3rd level by [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.index.droplevel(2).isin(mux)]
print (df)
        ColB colA
A1 B2 1  cb3  ca3
      2  cb4  ca4
A2 B1 1  cb5  ca5
      2  cb6  ca6
```

It working correct for any `index`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A1', 'B1'),('A2', 'B2')])

df = df[df.index.droplevel(2).isin(mux)]
print (df)
        ColB colA
A1 B1 1  cb1  ca1
      2  cb2  ca2
A2 B2 1  cb7  ca7
      2  cb8  ca8
```

Comment: Great, but is there a way to get it work with mixed index? I mean, I have a disordered MultiIndex and I want to get the resultant data frame to be disordered as well

Comment: @jwonlee - Not sure if understand, it should working nice also in `disordered MultiIndex`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for, you can try.

```
    df[('A1','B1')]
```

KR,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Let's try [`Advanced indexing with hierarchical index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)

```
df.loc[('A1', 'B2'):('A2','B1')]

Out[56]: 
        ColB colA
A1 B2 1  cb3  ca3
      2  cb4  ca4
A2 B1 1  cb5  ca5
      2  cb6  ca6
```