# Access rows of a pandas dataframe with matching Multiindex values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a `pandas` Dataframe with a Multi-Index (it can be accessed as a netcdf-file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FfvPgXPntrV7coPoVC-SXlM1BY7KksVC/view?usp=sharing)). The data looks like the picture below - the Multi-Index (`names=['rgi_id', 'time']`) is comprised of the glacier number (RGI60-15.00001 to RGI60-15.13000) and the point in time (2020 to 2101).

I want to extract all rows belonging to each glacier. I've extracted the unique values for the first part of the Multiindex like so: `uniques = np.unique(np.array(list(df.index.get_level_values(0))))`
But when I then want to isolate all rows using `uniques`, I get an empty dataframe:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index == uniques[0]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [hydro_year, hydro_month, calendar_year, calendar_month, volume, area, length, terminus_thick_0, terminus_thick_1, terminus_thick_2, water_level, glen_a, fs]
Index: []
```

I understand this is because `uniques` only consists of the first parts of the Multi-Index and therefore does not match. But now I am out of ideas on how to incorporate the second part of the Multi-Index.

How can I iterate through my dataframe and extract all rows belonging to each glacier? Am I on the right track or is there another solution? I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63572006/11728010) solution, but I cannot apply it correctly...

[image]

Comment: I can't access it; it has the extension `.nc` and is not a text file

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot to mention it in the question - the data is a netcdf file which I transformed into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.loc[uniques[0]]` to index on axis with labels in first level.